# JSON parse when top node is a number

Tags: json, api, parsing

I connect to various crypto public API's and get values using 3 steps:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("API URL",{muteHttpExceptions: true});
```

```
 var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

And then depending on the output format, I do one of the following:

```
Tickers:
   0:
      last_trade:
```

will result in me using:

```
var rate1 = json.tickers[0].last_trade;
```

```
result:
   XXRPXXBT:
      a:
         0:
```

will result in me using:

```
var rate1 = json.result.XXRPXXBT.a[0];
```

All of the methods I use work fine except when I get this format:

```
0:
   price:
1:
   price:
```

When I try use one of these, it does not work:

```
var rate1 = json[0].price;
var rate1 = json.[0].price;
var rate1 = json.0.price;
```

How do I read it when the top node is a number?

Comment: json["0"].price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to access a key that is a number you should enclose it in quotes like this (although even not enclosing it should work):

`json["0"].price`

The other 2 ways you tried are not a valid js syntax

Also check this link from MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#property_names

```js
var json = {
  0:{
    price: 100
  }
}

console.log(json["0"].price)


// Update for your enpoint in my comments

// Assuming that this have been parse and stored in a variable like the following on


let priceData = [
{
"symbol": "ETHBTC",
"price": "0.06643200"
  },
 {
"symbol": "LTCBTC",
"price": "0.00461600"
  }
]


///The above is an array

/// You access it via numeric indexes like that

console.log(priceData[0].price);

// However make sure that you have actually parsed your api response as a json object first
```

Comment: I know this answer is quite late but when I use the above method to get prices from the Binance public API (https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price), I get this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined". Why would this happen?

Comment: That  would happen when the response you get does not have the above format of my answer.

Comment: I will edit my answer to add some examples about the endpoint

Comment: I am using this:
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price",{muteHttpExceptions: true});
var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var rate1 = json["171"].price;
How do I add the response from the api to the variable priceData?

Comment: I tried this but not working (Am I close?):
var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
let priceData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  priceData.push(json[i].price)
};
var rate1 = priceData[171];

Comment: what is UrlFetchApp ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233652/discussion-between-manos-kounelakis-and-rowdogsa).